# Why can't you put a children <Widget>[] in a body: Center widget?

Tags: ios, flutter, syntax, widget

I'm trying to create a listview widget with a floating action button on my Flutter app, but it's not working because Android Studio keeps on telling me that:

- "the named parameter children isn't defined"
- I basically can't put children in a body: Center widget, but I don't know why

I'm basically a beginner to Flutter and I'm still a bit confused about the basic syntax, and which widgets can hold which widgets, so any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

**Here's my overall code that won't run due to the first error (in quotation marks above):**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(

    home: Home(),

  ));

  class Home extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[300],
          title: Text(
            'Welcome',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25.0,
              fontFamily: 'Raleway',
              letterSpacing: 1.0,
            ),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Center(
            children: <Widget> [
              ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.green[100],
                    child: Text(
                        'Body Text',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                          fontSize: 45.0,
                          letterSpacing: 1.0,
                          color: Colors.green[300],
                        ),
                      ),
                  ),

                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.green[100],
                    child: Text(
                      'Text'
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
            ),

            FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  '+',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                    fontSize: 35.0,
                  ),
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.green[300],
              ),
            ]
        ),
      );

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Because [`Center`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html) is a widget that does not take more than on widget as input.

It can only align one widget provided as a `child`.

For mulitple children you have to use some widget that takes a list of widgets as input.
Like:

- Column
- Row
- ListView
- Wrap
  etc.

Answer (score 1):

`child` parameter of `Center` Widget has a data type of `Widget` and so it can't take `<Widget>[]` as an input. It is similar to that an int won't accept String value. They are two different data types.

It seems that you want to have a list of data that is in center of the screen: For that you can use following code.

### 1.

```
Center(
 child: Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, // (optional) will center horizontally.
  children: <Widget>[
   .....
  ]
)
```

### 2.

```
Center(
    child: ListView(
      shrinkWrap:true;
      children: <Widget>[
       .....
      ]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Center accepts only one widget check laytout page at https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout

```
Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
     mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget> [
              ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.green[100],
                    child: Text(
                        'Body Text',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                          fontSize: 45.0,
                          letterSpacing: 1.0,
                          color: Colors.green[300],
                        ),
                      ),
                  ),

                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.green[100],
                    child: Text(
                      'Text'
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
            ),

            FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  '+',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                    fontSize: 35.0,
                  ),
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.green[300],
              ),
            ]
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of widgets, one of which accepts a widget as a child and the other one accepts [Widget] as children.

**Accepts a Widget as Child:** Container widget, **Center widget**, Padding widget, , etc.

**Accepts [Widget] as Children:** Row widget, Column widget, Stack widget, Wrap widget, ListView widget, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> [Center](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html) is a widget that centres its child within itself.

So you can have only 1 child inside `Center Widget`.

You can take structure like,

```
Center(
 child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
   All Children you have
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Center class :

A widget that centers its child within itself.

All layout widgets have either of the following:

A child property if they take a single child—
for example, Center or Container

A children property if they take a list of widgets—
for example, Row, Column, ListView, or Stack.

Add the Text widget to the Center widget:

const Center(
child: Text('Hello World'),
),